# android wait for animation to finish before activity ends

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I am writing an game application.  If the user presses the wrong button I want to show an animation and when the animation is complete then finish() my game;

currently, my animation just starts when the finished is called. I want the animation to complete.

Below is my class that implements AnimationListener

```
public final class DisplayNextView implements Animation.AnimationListener {
    View changeView;
    Drawable image;

    public DisplayNextView(View parChangeView, Drawable parImage) {
        this.changeView = parChangeView;
        this.image = parImage;
    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        changeView.post(new SwapViews(changeView, image));
        changeView.postDelayed(new SwapViews(changeView, null), 1000);
    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
}
```

This is my main activity method that starts the animation

```
private void applyRotation(View parChangeView, Drawable image, float start, float end) {
        // Find the center of image
        final float centerX = parChangeView.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        final float centerY = parChangeView.getHeight() / 2.0f;

        // Create a new 3D rotation with the supplied parameter
        // The animation listener is used to trigger the next animation
        final Flip3DAnimation rotation =
               new Flip3DAnimation(start, end, centerX, centerY);
        rotation.setDuration(250);
        rotation.setFillAfter(true);
        rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView (parChangeView,image));
        parChangeView.startAnimation(rotation);
        //return rotation;
        }
```

This is my the SwapView class this is a thread

```
public final class SwapViews implements Runnable {
    View changeView;
    Drawable image;

    public SwapViews(View parChangeView, Drawable parImage) {
        this.changeView = parChangeView;
        this.image = parImage;
    }

    public void run() {
        final float centerX = changeView.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        final float centerY = changeView.getHeight() / 2.0f;
        Flip3DAnimation rotation;
        changeView.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
        //TODO should find a better way!!
        if (image==null)
            changeView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


        rotation = new Flip3DAnimation(-90, 0, centerX, centerY);


        rotation.setDuration(250);
        rotation.setFillAfter(true);
        rotation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        changeView.startAnimation(rotation);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific as what this 'animation' is? Is it a class where you play frames yourself or just an image or video?

if it's the first the best way is to create a callback method and just fire that when the animation is done.

Comment: I am starting the animation from my main activity.  I am using custom class for animation and animation listener. I modified the example from http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html for animation.  The animation is of an image.

The user clicks a button and if the "answer" is wrong, then a card flips to show that his result is wrong and then I want to finish the activity. However, my activity finishes before the animation is completed.  Also, when the user clicks on the right button, there is the same animation with the card showing the correct result.

Comment: You're saying that you're using an animation listener. Are you using the AnimationListener's onAnimationEnd() callback? i need some example code to see exactly what you're doing. it's hard to just guess =/

Comment: thanks for your response and all your help.  I have updated my question and added in the code. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public final class DisplayNextView implements Animation.AnimationListener {
View changeView;
Drawable image;
boolean mIsCorrect;
Activity mContext;

public DisplayNextView(View parChangeView, Drawable parImage,
        boolean isCorrect, Activity context) {
    this.changeView = parChangeView;
    this.image = parImage;
    mIsCorrect = isCorrect;
    mContext = context;
}

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    changeView.post(new SwapViews(changeView, image));
    changeView.postDelayed(new SwapViews(changeView, null), 1000);
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (mIsCorrect == false) {
        mContext.finish();
    }
}

public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
}
```

And your applyRotation should be passed whether or not the guess was correct:

```
private void applyRotation(View parChangeView, Drawable image, float start,
        float end, boolean isCorrect) {
    // Find the center of image
    final float centerX = parChangeView.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    final float centerY = parChangeView.getHeight() / 2.0f;

    // Create a new 3D rotation with the supplied parameter
    // The animation listener is used to trigger the next animation
    final Flip3DAnimation rotation = new Flip3DAnimation(start, end,
            centerX, centerY);
    rotation.setDuration(250);
    rotation.setFillAfter(true);
    rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(parChangeView, image, isCorrect, this));
    parChangeView.startAnimation(rotation);
    // return rotation;
}
```